# BEKKS package in R. Are you supposed to feed residual of a mean equation model into the BEKK.fit or the return series?

Tags: r, garch, vector-autoregression

I am trying to use the BEKKs Package in R.

For context, my plan is to fit a VAR model of index prices to obtain the residuals. Then feed the residual into the BEKK.fit function.
However, I am not sure if the data object in the function should be the index prices or the residual of the mean equation. Please help to clarify what kind of data should I put in the function bekk.fit.

Looking at the source code, to my understanding, the data to fit in the function bekk.fit is supposed to be the residuals from the mean equation.
However, the manual example used bond price instead of the residual to put into the function, which confused me.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BEKKs/BEKKs.pdf

Comment: I think residuals are the right input to `BEKKs`.

Answer (score 0):

both are correct it depends on what you are trying to accomplish. GARCH models can stand on its own if applied to first difference of a series. Or, in your case, use a VAR-GARCH framework by applying either VAR or VECM (if cointegrated) and then use the residuals in a BEKK-GARCH model, commonly used to study volatility spillover.

Comment: You say *both are correct*, but I do not think supplying index prices as the input to BEKK would be a good idea. These should at least be first differenced.